# remote desktop connection with win7

Tags: windows

I had OS win7 and I had problem when I connected to server from my PC by remote desktop connection I couldnot connect altought I managed all settings for connection any one help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can check basic connectivity by pinging the server first, from the command prompt.  If the server is behind a firewall, confirm in the firewall settings that incoming RDP connections are permitted (TCP port 3389 by default).

Windows 7 uses a newer version of the terminal services client which can perform server authentication.  Check that you have set this (in Advanced settings) to "Warn me" or "Connect and do not warn me" if you're connecting to Windows Server 2003 or earlier.

If you're specifying a user name and domain, check that these are correct and that the user has authority to make RDP connections to the server, eg as a member of the appropriate group.

If you can post the error and more information about the environment then we could offer other help.

Comment: it didnot work I checked all but i didnot log to server

Comment: and how can i do that  If the server is behind a firewall, confirm in the firewall settings that incoming RDP connections are permitted (TCP port 3389 by default)?

Comment: You need to use the configuration tool for the firewall.  If it is a consumer firewall such as a broadband router, then there should be a web interface that you can use.  If it is not your firewall then you need to contact the person or company that manages it.

Answer (score 0):

Also try remote access programs like RHUB, VNC, TeamViewer and LogMeIn. It is definitely a lot easier to set up. RHUB is my favorite out of all four since there's features like file transfer plus I also use it for web conferencing as well.